# WordPress Install Error [Unknown character set: 'utf']

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, utf-8

I am trying to install the latest version of WordPress(4.6.1) in a local dev project environment. I just got a new iMac and I am in the process of moving my local instances of my projects to the new machine.

I am using Sequel Pro (v 1.1.2) to manage my databases & MAMP (3.4) to run my local server.

The connection to the database works as intended and I get to step 2 of the installation process however after putting in the following and clicking install there are errors and no tables are created in my database.

- Site Title,
- Username,
- Password,
- email,

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am sure its something dumb. Just need another set of eyes. Thanks!

**WordPress database install error:**

```
WordPress database error: [Unknown character set: 'utf']

CREATE TABLE wp_users (
    ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, 
    user_login varchar(60) NOT NULL default '', 
    user_pass varchar(255) NOT NULL default '', 
    user_nicename varchar(50) NOT NULL default '', 
    user_email varchar(100) NOT NULL default '', 
    user_url varchar(100) NOT NULL default '', 
    user_registered datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    user_activation_key varchar(255) NOT NULL default '', 
    user_status int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
    display_name varchar(250) NOT NULL default '', 
    PRIMARY KEY (ID), KEY user_login_key (user_login), 
    KEY user_nicename (user_nicename), 
    KEY user_email (user_email) ) 
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf-8

WordPress database error: [Unknown character set: 'utf']

CREATE TABLE wp_usermeta ( 
    umeta_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, 
    user_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
    meta_key varchar(255) default NULL, 
    meta_value longtext, 
    PRIMARY KEY (umeta_id), 
    KEY user_id (user_id), 
    KEY meta_key (meta_key(191)) )

DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf-8

WordPress database error: [Unknown character set: 'utf']

CREATE TABLE wp_termmeta ( 
    meta_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, 
    term_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
    meta_key varchar(255) default NULL, 
    meta_value longtext, 
    PRIMARY KEY (meta_id), 
    KEY term_id (term_id), 
    KEY meta_key (meta_key(191)) )

DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf-8
```

**wp-config.php file**

```
/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf-8');
```

**The database itself is set at:**

Database Encoding: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Database Collation: utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */   
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
```

[WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Database_character_set)

Comment: Wow! I can't believe I missed that hyphen. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the DDL format you've got than this will work.

```
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
```